# Fuse on android

Tags: android, linux, mount, fuse

I'm trying to use FUSE to mount a virtual FS on a rooted android.
I've compiled a simple [program](https://github.com/Vayu/libfuse-android/blob/android/example/hello_ll.c) that mounts a readonly virtual FS containing a single file (`hello`) containing the contents `Hello world`.

After compiling the program, I ran (as root)

```
mkdir /mnt/test
chmod 777 /mnt/test
a.out -d -oallow_other mnt/test
```

When I run `ls /mnt/test` as a root user, everything works as expected.

When I run `ls /mnt/test` as any other user, or from any other application (explorer / adb shell), I receive the contents of the underlying filesystem (in this case, the root filesystem) instead of the output from the FUSE fs.

After digging into it a little, I found out that the FUSE mounts don't show up when running `cat /proc/mounts` as a user, but it does show up as root. Does android (or maybe even linux ?) have special facility for hiding mountpoints to specific users ?

**Solution:**
 I decided to run my program as daemon in initrc, and it's work well

```
on post-fs-data
    start hello

service hello /sbin/hello
    seclabel u:r:su:s0
```

Comment: Came here while trying to search the same thing...have you had any luck thus far?

Comment: Yes, I think my issue come from VM and namespacing of android, so I decided to get all rights, and run my program as daemon in initrc. And it's work well now !

Comment: Sounds like SELinux restrictions: https://source.android.com/security/selinux/